# SWT: How to get a Composite to automatically fill it's container

Tags: java, layout, swt

In the following code I use SWT and also draw2d.  When I run the program however nothing shows up.  After some debugging I've found it to be because the container's size are all 0. I have to manually enter a size like

```
    canvasData.heightHint = 500;
    canvasData.widthHint = 500;
```

This is fine and dandy but I need these containers to fit themselves into the space given to them by form.  Is there any way to accomplish this? Any advice would be helpful.

```
/* (non-Javadoc)
 * @see org.eclipse.ui.forms.editor.FormPage#createFormContent(org.eclipse.ui.forms.IManagedForm)
 */
@Override
protected void createFormContent( IManagedForm managedForm ) 
{
    super.createFormContent(managedForm);

    ScrolledForm form = managedForm.getForm();  

    Composite tabParent = managedForm.getToolkit().createComposite(form.getBody());
    GridData tabParentData = new GridData(SWT.FILL,SWT.FILL,true,true);
    tabParent.setLayoutData(tabParentData);
    tabParent.setLayout(new GridLayout());

    FigureCanvas canvas = new FigureCanvas(tabParent);
    GridData canvasData = new GridData(SWT.FILL,SWT.FILL,true,true);        
    canvas.setLayoutData(canvasData);

    //diagramContents is an IFigure from draw2d. it holds other IFigures, Labels, ect. 
    //Essentially everything being displayed
    canvas.setContents(diagramContents); 

    //This method is what creates everything being displayed (the stuff in diagramContents)
    refreshDisplayFromModel();

    canvas.pack();  
    tabParent.pack();   
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Throw out `GridLayout` and `GridData` and try to set a `FillLayout` onto `tabParent` like this:

```
form.getBody().setLayout(new FillLayout()); //*

Composite tabParent = managedForm.getToolkit().createComposite(form.getBody());
tabParent.setLayout(new FillLayout());

FigureCanvas canvas = new FigureCanvas(tabParent);
//no layouting
canvas.setContents(diagramContents);
```

`FillLayout` doesn't need a constraints object and just makes its child grab everything. If you have more than one child, I propose you take a look at `RowLayout` for simple stuff and `FormLayout` for complex stuff, and just forget about `GridLayout`.

You can get rid of the `pack()` calls aswell.

*: Since you gave `tabParent` a `GridData` object aswell, I figured your form has a `GridLayout`. Got rid of that for you, too.

Comment: I could kiss you.  It's not even funny how long this stupid thing has stumped me. I honestly don't even remember why I was using the GridLayout.

Comment: @Chrus ah, I'm very happy that I could help you. I don't know where the obsession with GridLayout comes from, but I'm encountering this in every SWT legacy project I'm called to. Most custom framework have extensive support for it or even assume that all that's ever going to be used will be Grid.. it's a real pain to liberate products from that yoke :) Have a nice day!

Answer (score 0):

Use

```
canvas.getViewPort().setContentsTracksWidth( true );
canvas.getViewPort().setContentsTracksHeight( true );
```

Comment: This doesn't do anything.  Might it be because canvas is inside tabParent which is inside form?